# Trying to list strings in a config sectiong

Tags: java

Okay I don't know how to explain this but if you look a

```
Players:
  _Brand0n_:
    'Fourm Link:': 'Null'
    'Registered:': 'No'
    'GamePoints:': '0'
    'UUID:': 94bad256-7fa0-49c6-add1-50b61a854dc3
    Reports:
      '#R:': '0'
      'TheeLux:': Hacking  Time: Fri Jul 22 12:21:35 CDT 2016'
      'Adam_Hall:': Hacking  Time: Fri Jul 22 12:21:35 CDT 2016'
```

I need to be able to take the reports from TheeLux and Adam_Hall and print an msg saying

Adam_Hall: Hacking - Time: Fri Jul 22 12:21:35 CDT 2016

But I don't know how to take however many configuration sections and make them into strings ext. If this is confusing please post a comment and I'll try and clarify.

Comment: Is your problem by any chance being caused by the `'`s without a corresponding single quote at the end of the last two lines?

Comment: Yes please especially this part : `however many configuration sections and make them into strings ext.`

Comment: @svasa What I really need is to add all the reports into an arraylist, so the list would include TheeLux and Adam_Hall with their reports.

Comment: Is this from a file? Is the file tab delimited ? Do you need only "Hacking Times " ?

Comment: @svasa No right now if I do report (Name) (Rule Broken) then it will add it to a data file,

Comment: What do you mean by `I do report (Name) (Rule Broken)`

Comment: @svasa its a mc plugin

Comment: MC plugin and YAML; I'm guessing you're talking about Bukkit?